# Accessing USB drive attached to Router

Tags: networking, usb, permissions, fstab, router

I have a USB drive attached to my Zyxel XMG3927  Router.  I have set up access permissions at the router and the device can be seen in my file manager - listed as:

USB_Storage on 192.168.1.1

I followed some advice on this forum and others and have got part way to accessing the drive. I have cifs-utils installed on my Ubuntu 20.04 system and the following file added to /etc/fstab/:
//192.168.1.1/USB_Storage /media/pat/public cifs guest 0 0

The device and the directories and contents can be seen and accessed from my laptop running 21.04 over the wireless network without problems however on trying to access the drive from my desktop (wired connection) I am given the message: "An error occurred while accessing 'Home', the system responded: mount: /media/pat/public: operation permitted for root only."

If I type smb://192.168.1.1/ into Nautilus I am shown the directories on the drive but on trying to access them I am given the message "Failed to mount windows share: Invalid Argument"

I can see the directories - how do I get into them on my desktop computer please?  Any and all help appreciated.
Thank you..

Comment: What OS and version are you running on the desktop?

Comment: The desktop is running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: System is running Ubuntu 20.04